# Form based authentication in JBoss successful but throws 408 error page

Tags: web-applications, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate my java application from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss 7.0. I am able to deploy the application, but if I want to login (form based authentication), I get a 408 (time out) error page. Check out this extract from **server.log**:

```
10:06:52,997 TRACE [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) End isValid, true
10:06:52,997 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) User: tlubrpa1 is authenticated
10:06:52,997 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) Authentication of 'tlubrpa1' was successful
10:06:52,998 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SSIS2_1]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) User took so long to log on the session expired
10:06:52,998 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5)  Failed authenticate() test ??/SSIS2_1/View/Mainpage/j_security_check
10:06:53,511 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1311062813511 sessioncount 0
10:06:53,512 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
10:06:54,181 TRACE [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Scanning directory C:\java\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments for deployment content changes
```

This is my the corresponding extract from **standalone.xml**:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="SSIS2-domain">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/SSIS2DSDev"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=? AND active=1"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT USERROLE.rolename, 'Roles' FROM USERS INNER JOIN (USERROLE INNER JOIN MAPUSERUSERROLE ON USERROLE.roleid = MAPUSERUSERROLE.roleid) ON USERS.userid = MAPUSERUSERROLE.userid where USERS.username=?"/>
                        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

The security stuff is actually the same like in the login-config.xml from JBoss 5.1, and as you can see above it authenticates the user.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is actually a bug. There is a workaround. Add this to **standalone.xml** right after the  element:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: Hey buddy, where exactly I need to add it in standalone.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

This **408 timeout error** occurs when you directly go to the login.jsf page. This page must be understood as an interceptor for secure areas.

For exemple with the web.xml written below, you want to secure the /secure/home page. You will be redirected to your login page and you will not see the 408 error.

```
<security-constraint>
<display-name>global access</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>everyone</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
...
</security-constraint>
...
```